# How does MIPS determine the starting address of an array?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I am working on a problem in MIPS where I need to declare an array and a variable, which I do in the following block:

```
    .data
    array: .space 10
    length: .word 0

    .text 
    #the rest of the code
```

Now why does the address of the variable length starts exactly 12 bytes after the starting address of array, even though array takes 10 bytes of memory?

Comment: If it doing that, it is because `.word` defines a 32 bit number (i.e. 4 bytes), and thus, `length` must be aligned on a 4 byte boundary. And, the assembler is doing that alignment automatically [as a convenience to you vs. an assembler error].

Comment: Craig Estey that could be an answer rather than a comment